# Non-Negative solutions in Nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A$ and a column vector $\vec{x}$. The number of columns of $A$ is much larger than the number of rows. All entries $a_{ij}$ of $A$ are non-negative. I know there is a vector $\vec{s}$ with scalar elements $s_i>=0$ so that:
$$
A*\vec{s}=\vec{x}
$$
I compute $\vec{s}$ by using a non-negative least squares solver (from Scipy).

My goal is to compute at least one more vector $s'$ that fullfills the equation
$$
A*\vec{s'}=\vec{x}
$$
with $s_i'>=0$.

For this I compute the Nullspace of $A$. Let $B$ be its base and $b_i$ the columns of $B$. I can now produce $s'$
$$
s'=s+\sum \lambda_ib_i
$$
I now struggle with the problem of finding appropriate $\lambda_i$s (besides all being 0) so that the non-negativity constraint on the entries of $s'$ is fullfilled.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: In the first line you have written that $A$ is a base, but in the sequence $A$ is a matrix. Is $A$  intended as a matrix with linearly independent vectors as columns? If that is the case, it is contradicted by the fact that the number of columns is much larger than the number of rows, so the columns cannot be independent.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification request @jobe. I reformulated the question and hope it becomes clearer now.

Comment: One more thing: what do you mean by $\text{dim}(A)$? The matrix $A$ is not square, so its dimension is specified by two different numbers, while the rank needs only one. This makes a comparison between rank and dimension at least ambiguous.

Comment: @jobe: I deleted the confusing lines since they are not necessary for the problem anyways.